# Static resource in MAUI class library style not found

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am working on several MAUI applications and in the process I have decided to create a "toolkit" class library where I put reusable code. I have created several ResourceDictionary for Colors and Styles, they are the one prefixed by "tt":

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            <tt:MaterialColorsTeal x:Name="materialColors"/>
            <tt:TimerColors  x:Name="timerColors"/>
            <tt:ControlStyles/> <----- This one causes the exception
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The last one causes an exception on this line because it does not know about the static resource "Primary":

```
 <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
```

What I don't get, is that this value "Primary" has been defined already in the "Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" dictionary and overriden in the "tt:MaterialColorsTeal" dictionary. Is there something specific to do in the class library (from where "tt" is imported) to link the static resources of the different dictionaries between each other ?

I'm missing something here and would really appreciate some guidance on the reason of the issue, thanks for any help.

Exception is:

> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 12:44.
> StaticResource not found for key Primary'

and thrown in App ctor at:

```
    InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: There is `<Color x:Key="Premary"></Color>` in MAUI project/Resources/Colors.xaml profile, did you removed that and add new `<Color x:Key="Premary">` in `<tt:ControlStyles/>`?

Comment: I did not remove it, I do have a "Primary" color in project/Resources/Colors and I have one in <tt:ControlStyles/> as well. My intended use case is to have the "Primary" color used to be the one defined in <tt:ControlStyles/> and that is why I include it after in the dictionary (for overriding the first). Ideally I would like to not have to define "Primary" in my project color file, but this got me exceptions when Styles in project/Resources/Styles.xaml tried to use "Primary". I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I added the library with Resource Dictionary file to Maui project and no error occurred. My steps: Add ResourceDictionary file in Library, the main code in Dctionary file is `<Color x:key="Primary">#00ff00</Color> <Style TargetType="Button"> <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" /></Style>`, then add the Library to Maui Depencies. In Maui App.xaml file, I add `xmlns:tt="cls-namespace:MauiLib;assembly=MauiLib" into <Application>`, then invoke the Dictionary file like your code. Are these steps the same as yours? Or you can try the steps in an empty MAUI project.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this. Following your step does work, the difference with my code is that I define the Colors and the Styles in two different dictionaries (and files therefore).  I thought style values would be resolved all together when all of them are known but it seems that a resource dictionary needs to know about all the styles it references in its scope so I put all the color names I may use in a BaseColors dictionary which I reference with MergedDictionary in my ControlStyles dictionary.

Comment: I'm glad your problem has been resolved.